# How to get a part of tag in XML (iOS)

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can I get some data from the tag of a xml file?

I have a tag like this:

```
`<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8580/directory/playlists/" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" />`
```

I would like to save the http link: http://127.0.0.1:8580/directory/playlists/

Can I use the NSXMLParser?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a delegate for the `NSXMLParser` that conforms to the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol. In this implementation implement at least this method:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                                       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                                      qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
                                         attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        NSString* href = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];
        // Do you stuff with the href
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you are after "http://127.0.0.1:8580/directory/playlists/" is called an attribute.  It is the attribute of the element "link".

Check out the Apple documentation relating to XML processing and elements and attributes.  For example, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html